# Delay handling of registrations

Tags: java, thread-safety

I'm trying to solve the problem of a whiteboard receiving registrations before, during and after its own initialization. As each registration needs a bit of handling which can happen only after the whiteboard is fully initialized, I need to delay that handling, until initialization has completed. All of this needs to be managed in a thread safe manner, as registrations may happen by multiple threads.

So I've devised the component below to help the whiteboard achieve this.

I've made this interface :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RegistrationHandler {

    void handle(Runnable registration);

    default void ready() {
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation that helps me delay

```
public final class DelayedRegistrationHandler implements RegistrationHandler {
    private volatile RegistrationHandler state = new QueuedHandler();

    @Override
    public void handle(Runnable registration) {
        state.handle(registration);
    }

    @Override
    public void ready() {
        RegistrationHandler queued = state;
        state = Runnable::run;
        queued.ready();
    }

    private static class QueuedHandler implements RegistrationHandler {

        private final Queue<Runnable> registrations = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        @Override
        public void handle(Runnable registration) {
            registrations.add(registration);
        }

        public void ready() {
            while (!registrations.isEmpty()) {
                registrations.remove().run();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Intended usage (added for clarification, not actual code, not for review)

```
RegistrationHandler registrationHandler = new DelayedRegistrationHandler();

public void register(Object registered) {
    registrationHandler.handle(() -> this.doActualRegistration(registered));
}

public void init() {
    doHeavyInitPossiblyWaitingForOtherServices();
    registrationHandler.ready();
}
```

**My primary goal for this review is asserting the thread safety of the implementation.** But obviously all remarks are welcome.

Comment: You don't appear to have created any threads, what are you talking about? Where are the threads coming from that require thread safety?

Comment: And, does this even compile? I don't have my ide with me right now -- I'm on my phone writing this -- so I can't check, but Runnable::run should return void, so it shouldn't be assignable to state.

Comment: It's the clients that register with the whiteboard that may do so from different threads, the whiteboard itself, nor this component to help the whiteboard are supposed to create extra threads.

Comment: @EngineerDollery `Runnable::run` is a method reference equivalent with lambda `runnable -> runnable.run()`, both of which satisfy the `RegistrationHandler` functional interface, the type of `state`. Compiles and runs just fine